# delete subfolders without deleting parent folder

Tags: rm

For this type of dir structure :

```
/config/filegroups/filegroupA/files/fileA1.txt
/config/filegroups/filegroupA/files/fileA2.txt
/config/filegroups/filegroupB/files/fileB1.txt
/config/filegroups/filegroupB/files/fileB2.txt
...
```

I know that I can use `rm -rf /config/filesgroups` to delete parent folder and all sub-folders ...

but I want to delete only `/filegroupA` , `/filegroupB` , etc. , and not delete `/config/filegroups`

Comment: Is there any problem to use rm -rf /config/filesgroups/* ?

Comment: Or maybe even `rm -rf /config/filegroups/filegroups{A,B}` ?

Comment: @dsumsky By default `bash` doesn't include '.' folders in pathname expansion. Which may or may not be desired. Myself I do `shopt -s dotglob` in `.bashrc` to fix that. Just a side note that somebody might find useful ;).

Comment: Did any o fthis work for you? If so, would you mind accepting an answer, in order to help others (likw me) who want to do the same thing?

Answer (score 41):

```
rm -rf /config/filegroups/*
```

If you want to delete only directories (and symlinks to directories), leaving any files in `/config/filegroups` untouched, you can use a trailing slash:

```
rm -rf /config/filegroups/*/
```

If you want to delete directories with names beginning with a `.` as well, assuming you have a fairly recent bash, you should use the dotglob shell option:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -rf /config/filegroups/*/
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: and please not that it will not work for rm -rf "/config/filegroups/*"

Answer (score 8):

I prefer using `find` with `-exec`, that would make your call something like this:

```
find /config/filegroups/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

This will delete all files and directories under `/config/filegroups` including "hidden" files and directories (names starting with `.`).

```
find /config/filegroups -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs rm -rf
```

If the file or directory names contain spaces you have to do it like this:

```
find /config/filegroups -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Bonus: you can first check what is going to be deleted like this:

```
find /config/filegroups -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

If you want to keep certain files or directories you can do it like this:

```
find /config/filegroups -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name "keep"
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `find`'s `-delete` option?

Comment: `-delete` refuses to delete non empty directories. `-maxdepth` overrides `-depth`, which is needed by `-delete` to delete non empty directories. Without `-maxdepth` you cannot easily see which directories are going to be deleted because it also lists the files inside the directories. Not using `-maxdepth` also means you cannot easily use filters like `-name`. Furthermore `-delete` deletes the directories by deleting all the objects inside first, which can take a long time if it is a big and deep tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```shell
find /config/filegroups/* -type d -name filegroupA -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are already in the folder you can just type `rm -rf ./**`

So:

```
cd /config/filesgroups
rm -rf ./**
```

This is a glob pattern to delete all the subfolders from the local path..

`./` referring to the local folder... and `**` for all the folders beneath..

Comment: Which folder, and why `**``

Comment: This would be exactly the same as `rm -rf ./*`, except that you are likely to get diagnostic messages about "No such file or directory" if you're not using `-f` in your command (since the top-most directory would be recursively deleted before its contents is processed by `rm`).